# Computability of the "free envelope rank" of an endomorphism of a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups, combinatorics-on-words

Let $F$ be a free group freely generated by the finite set $S$ and $\sigma\colon F\to F$ be a group morphism. We define the *free envelope rank* of $\sigma$, written $r(\sigma)$, as the smallest $k$ for which we can find a group $\sigma(F) \leq H \leq F$ having free rank equal to $k$. This definition makes sense since any subgroup of $F$ is free

Observe that $\sigma$ is determined by its values on $S$. If the values $\sigma(S) := \{\sigma(s) : s \in S\}$ are known, is there an algorithm to compute $r(\sigma)$? EDIT: as @HJRW pointed out, $r(\sigma)$ is computable.

Now, it is clear that $r(\sigma) \geq r(\sigma^2) \geq r(\sigma^3) \geq \dots$, where $\sigma^n$ is the morphism obtained by composing $\sigma$ with itself $n$ times. Thus, $R(\sigma) := \lim_{n\to\infty}r(\sigma^n) = \inf_{n\geq1}r(\sigma^n)$. **My question is: given the values $\sigma(S)$, is $R(\sigma)$ computable?**

The following observation may be relevant. Let $|\sigma| = \max_{s\in S}d_S(\sigma(a),1)$, where $d_S$ is the [word metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric) with respect to $S$. Then, $R(\sigma)$ is computable if and only if for any morphism $\sigma$ there exists $n_0$ depending only on $|\sigma|$ and $\#F$ such that $R(\sigma) = r(\sigma^{n_0})$.

Also, I could not find a morphism with $n_0 > 1$, so an example satisfying this condition would be interesting for me.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Your $r(\sigma)$ is clearly computable. Suppose that $\sigma(F)$ corresponds to an immersion of a core graph $\Delta$ into $\Gamma$. Then $r(\sigma)$ is the smallest rank of a core graph $\Xi$ such that $\Delta\to\Gamma$ factors through $\Xi$. Since $\Delta$ wlog surjects $\Xi$, there are only finitely many possibilities to check.

Comment: I don't really the see the point in restricting to images of endomorphisms. The natural setting seems to start from an arbitrary finitely generated subgroup of $F$ (given by generators).

Comment: @YCor How would you define the iterates $\sigma^n(F)$ in that context?

Comment: Yes, I should have explicitly referred to the first question, which was initially boldfaced and called "first question".